# AngularJS unit-test 'ReferenceError: humane is not defined'

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am attempting to incorporate the [humane.js notification library](http://wavded.github.io/humane-js/) into my AngularJS app. I have wrapped the humane.js use into an Angular service, and the app is working correctly. But when I attempt to write unit tests for the Angular service, I get the following error when attempting to execute the first test of this service:

```
ReferenceError: humane is not defined
```

My karma.conf file contains the reference to the humane.js file:

```
files: [
  'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'bower_components/messageformat/messageformat.js',
  'bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js',
  'bower_components/angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat/angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat.js',
  'bower_components/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js',
  'bower_components/momentjs/moment.js',
  'other_components/highcharts-ng/src/directives/highcharts-ng.js',
  'other_components/keylines/keylines.js',
  'other_components/logging/log4javascript.js',
  'bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
  'bower_components/humane-js/humane.js',
  'scripts/*.js',
  'scripts/*/*.js',
  'resources/defaultTranslations.js',
  'test/unit/*/*.js',
  'views/*.html'
],
```

I can't figure out what's going wrong. If I replace Humane.js with an otherwise similar notification library - [alertify.js](http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/) - and do the exact same thing, I do not get the error.

What am I missing? Like I said, the application works, including the notification portion. Only the unit tests are affected. The Humane.js module uses some unusual (to me) self-executing module syntax:

```
;!function (name, context, definition) {
  if (typeof module !== 'undefined') module.exports = definition(name, context)
  else if (typeof define === 'function' && typeof define.amd  === 'object') define(definition)
  else context[name] = definition(name, context)
}('humane', this, function (name, context) {
```

...module definitions here...

```
   return new Humane()
})
```

I'm wondering if this is confusing the karma loader somehow. The other library (alertify.js) does not have this structure.

Comment: could you gist the finished angular wrapper you used in the end? It would be really helpful!

Comment: I'm afraid that I ended up abandoning trying to use humane.js shortly after posting this, so I don't have anything to offer you. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Got here while trying to figure out a different Karma error. It might not be related but I see your karma file paths look different that to me. I usually use the default generated via the angular-generator and it products something like this in my karma kong:

```
        files     : [
            'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
            'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
            'app/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
            'app/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
            'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js'
            ...
        ],
```